# Showing rows that are locked in Oracle

Tags: oracle, locking

Using Oracle, is it possible to indicate which rows are currently locked (and which are not) when performing a select statement (I don't want to lock any rows, just be able to display which are locked)?

For example, a pseudo column that would return the lock/transaction against the row:
    SELECT lockname FROM emp;

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/node/854

Comment: Why do you want to display which rows are locked?  If the intention is to prevent someone from trying to lock a row that someone else is already processing, it's likely easier to just select the unlocked rows using SKIP LOCKED (depending on the Oracle version, this may or may not be available/ documented).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: There's no blocking going on so putting the values in to dbms_rowid.rowid_create from v$session creates a rowid that doesn't exist in the table (at least that's why I'm guessing it didn't work).

@Justin Cave: Yes, that's my intention. SKIP LOCKED sounds like it might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is this - although it is not terribly efficient and so I wouldn't want to do use it for large data sets. Create a row-level function to try and lock the row. If it fails, then the row is already locked

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_row_locked (v_rowid ROWID, table_name VARCHAR2)
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   x   NUMBER;
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'Begin
                           Select 1 into :x from '
                              || table_name
                              || ' where rowid =:v_rowid for update nowait;
                         Exception
                            When Others Then
                              :x:=null;
                         End;'
   USING OUT x, v_rowid;

   -- now release the lock if we got it. 
   ROLLBACK;

   IF x = 1
   THEN
      RETURN 'N';
   ELSIF x IS NULL
   THEN
      RETURN 'Y';
   END IF;
END;
/
```

And then you could

```
Select field1, field2, is_row_locked(rowid, 'MYTABLE') from mytable;
```

It will work, but it isn't pretty nor efficient.

Indeed, it has exactly one redeeming quality - it will work even if you don't have select privs on the various v$ tables required in the linked document. If you have the privs, though, definitely go the other route.

Comment: I cant go the other route as there is no blocking going on, so I cant make the rowid from the v$session info. Is requesting a lock the only way to find out if there is a lock? All the text online I read suggests a row lock is the transaction id applied to the row. Makes it sounds like it should be something that's easy to get at :(

Comment: @Cwoo what make you think getting a locked status per row is that easy?  This is just one of that points where you can't forget about complexity of concurrent systems and isolated transactions.

Comment: Cwoo, bear in mind that normally the user is expected to leave the transactional contols to the database and, at best, react to situations as they arise. And, for high-volume systems the database is probably doing a lot of the transactional control in memory rather than adding overhead by writing to a table structure. And even if my query DOES work, for a large table by the time you do your fetch and then try and process the results - who is to say that the locks are still what they were when you determined them? Most, after all, do not exist for very long

Comment: Alrighty, I guess this is something I probably shouldn't be trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

> *is it possible to indicate which rows are currently locked (and which are not) when performing a select statement*

A SELECT statement will never lock any rows - unless you ask it to by using FOR UPDATE.

If you want to see locks that are held due to a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE (or a real update), you can query the v$lock system view.

See the link that OMG Pony posted for an example on how to use that view.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Michael Broughton's answer is the only way that will always work.  This is because V$LOCK is not accurate 100% of the time.

Sessions don't wait for a row, they wait for the end of the transaction that modified that row.  Most of the time those two concepts are the same thing, but not when you start using savepoints.

For example:

- Session 1 creates a savepoint and modifies a row.
- Session 2 tries to modify that same
  row, but sees session 1 already has that row,
  and waits for session 1 to finish.
- Session 1 rolls back to the
  savepoint.  This removes its entry
  from the ITL but does not end the
  transaction.  Session 2 is still
  waiting on session 1.  According to
  V$LOCK session 2 is still waiting on
  that row, but that's not really true
  because now session 3 can modify that
  row.  (And if session 1 executes a
  commit or rollback, session 2 will
  wait on session 3.)

Sorry if that's confusing.  You may want to step through the link provided by OMG Ponies, and then try it again with savepoints.